# why textBox value from ViewBag is corrupted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a project with asp.net MVC 5 which I am new. At some point I retrieve a string from byte array and pass it to view with ViewBag

```
string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(metadatacontent.content);
ViewBag.content = content;
```

And I want to edit this field in the view.

```
@ViewBag.content // this line for checking
@Html.TextBox("metaData", (String)ViewBag.content)
```

What I see on the webpage is: log file (from @ViewBag.content) l�o�g� �f�i�l�e� (inside the textBox)

Why the string is broken inside the textBox?
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Edit: Here I converted the text from View into byte[] and stored it using the model.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[Request["metaData"].ToString().Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Request["metaData"].ToString().ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
metadatacontent.content = bytes;
```

Comment: what's `metadatacontent.content`? is it in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Actually when I was converting string to byte[] I didn't set any encoding. When converting back from byte[] to string I also tried it with System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString but the result was same

Comment: how did you convert it to `byte[]`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the part I converted to byte[].
First in create part I got the text from View and stored it. Now I want to edit this data. I also failed to convert byte[] to string in the View so I am converting it in the controller and passing it with ViewBag.

Comment: did you try with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(...)`?

Comment: I didn't. And now when I tried it worked thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up comments. Because you're not changing default format of the original `string` you need to use `Unicode` encoding instead of `UTF-8`:

```
string content = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(metadatacontent.content);
```